# Title attribute required for a hidden select field

Tags: html, select

I created a `select` in html that looks like

```
                        <select
                            multiple
                            name="carIds"
                            aria-hidden="true"
                            class="hide"
                            value.bind="carIds">
                        </select>
```

The problem I am facing is that PHPStorm reacts to this element with

> Form input without an associated label or title attribute
>   This inspection highlights form elements without required associated label (WCAG 2.0: H44) or title attribute (WCAG 2.0: H65) and provides the ability to create a new label or add an attribute

Why is the title required for a hidden element? Obviously, it makes no sense to set a label...

P.S. I tried setting the `hidden` attribute as well, but nothing changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**: don't search for a meaning in IDE warnings. The IDE tries to help you but sometimes it fails. If you can fix the warning and it makes sense - do it. If it does not make sense - skip it.

**The long version**

The reason of that is, most likely, that the state of the element can be changed when the page is displayed. The attribute `hidden` or class `hide` do not guarantee that the element will actually be hidden. E.g.:

```
[hidden] {
  display: block !important;
  visibility: visible !important;
}
```

will show this element.

This also can be changed by JavaScript in runtime: the attribute / class can be deleted and since that moment the element is visible. Even the `aria-hidden` attribute could be easily removed.

The most of the crawlers are not aware of CSS and of the fact the element is hidden. They would retrieve the whole HTML and process it as is.

The primary reason of all not-making-sense warnings is the IDE's inability to fully understand your needs and what you are doing because it cannot know what you are doing further on with this piece HTML.

Finally, this is just a warning (and there are lots of arguable warnings in IntelliJ / PHPStorm / WebStorm). It can always be skipped.

Comment: What about `aria-hidden`? Surely there is some way to indicate that an element is to be ignored by screen readers, etc.? Why would a screen reader want to know about a hidden input/select field?

Comment: it is not about screen readers. It is about the implementation of IDE. Just imagine yourself to be an author of IDE. The IDE does not know anything about your environment and needs. It tries to help you with some 'common' things, but sometimes it really fails. E.g. take `label` `for` tag and element with `id` that are generated automatically and generate them with different code snippets (e.g. add one space to the one that generates the `for` tag). And the IDE will complain that cannot find element with this `id` for this `for`.

Comment: The IDE could be more smart though. If it sees an `aria-hidden` attribute then it shouldn't show a warning. However, I'm not sure if that's valid in WCAG, I couldn't really find the details.

Comment: It would make sense, however lots of the warnings are really hard to be sure of. Most of HTML properties are HTML-version dependent (which is most of the time unknown for IDE), some of them are absolutely unnecessary like if I would skip `img`'s `src` attribute - 99.9999% of the clients would not really care. If I make an application that is not exposed to Google I would not care of any `alt` attributes but the IDE **does not know** your intentions. That is why it shows a stupid (from your perspective) warning.

Comment: @darkangel actually we are talking about two different things. My point is that nobody really cares of small problems in warnings because it is sometimes too complicated / there is no enough data to make proper decisions. The particular case you / OP are talking about is just one of a thousand of problems with those warnings.